# Sails many to many association

Tags: associations, sails.js

I have many to many association in Sails. As example Article and Authors (each article could be authored by many Authors and each Author can create many articles).

I have records for both Article and Author in DB already.

Where and what should I post to just associate records (vs create new records)?

I tried to post to

/article/:id following data

```
{ 
  id : 'articleid',
  authors : {
     id: 'authorid',
     name: 'authorName'
  }
}
```

However, it tries to create new author (instead of just associating it).

Also, do I need to do two do two post (to /articles and to /authors) or can I do just one post  and it will modify another thing automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blueprints API provides a couple of ways to do this.  If you want to create a brand new author and associate it with an existing article which has ID 1, you would do:

**POST /article/1/authors**

```
{
    name: 'authorName',
    ...other author data...
}
```

If you have an existing author that you want to associate with an article, you can simply do (for example if the author has ID 2):

**POST /article/1/authors/2**

with no body.